# Sigma field generated by Borel sets is the same as sigma field generated by intervals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{R} = \{ B_1 \times B_2 : B_1,B_2 \in \mathcal{B} \} $ where $\mathcal{B}$ is the sigma field of Borel sets. Let $\mathcal{I} = \{ I_1 \times I_2 : I_1,I_2 \; \; \text{are intervals} \} $. We want to show that $\sigma(\mathcal{R}) = \sigma( \mathcal{I} )$.

My try: We know that the Borel sets are generated by intervals, hence we must have $\mathcal{I} \subseteq \mathcal{R} $. Therefore, $\sigma( \mathcal{I} ) \subset \sigma( \mathcal{R} ) $. I am kind of stuck trying to prove the other direction. Can someone help me? It would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @DonAnselmo The bounty is odd...

Comment: @Did $250$ is even number

Comment: @DonAnselmo Makes it even odder... :-) Seriously, what do you expect from the bounty?

Comment: @DonAnselmo Apologies for the incomplete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show $\sigma(\mathcal R) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal I)$, it suffices to show $\mathcal R \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal I$) .

To show this, it again suffices to show that $\mathbb{R}\times B$ and $B\times\mathbb{R}$ belong to $\sigma(\mathcal I)$ for every $B \in \mathcal B$. This is because any $B_1\times B_2 = (\mathbb R\times B_2)\cap(B_1\times\mathbb R) $.

But now we claim that $\mathbb R \times B \in \sigma(\mathcal A)$ where $\mathcal A = \{\mathbb R\times I :  I \text{ is an interval} \}$. This follows because $$\{X:\mathbb R\times X \in\ \sigma(\mathcal A)\} $$ is itself a sigma field containing all the intervals and hence $B$ belongs to it.

As  $\mathcal A \subset \sigma(\mathcal I)$. We will have $\mathbb R \times B \in \sigma(\mathcal I)$ and similarly $B \times \mathbb R \in \sigma(\mathcal I)$. Hence the required conclusion follows.